# How to get text element in puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

I have two spans with text inside it like this.

```
<span class="date">today</span>
<span class="date">tomorrow</span>
```

I want to get those texts and `console.log()` it on my terminal. How can I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const html = `
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head><meta charset='UTF-8'><title>Test</title></head>
    <body>
      <span class="date">today</span>
      <span class="date">tomorrow</span>
    </body>
  </html>`;

(async function main() {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const [page] = await browser.pages();

    await page.goto(`data:text/html,${html}`);

    const texts = await page.evaluate(() => Array.from(
      document.querySelectorAll('span.date'),
      span => span.innerText
    ));

    console.log(texts); // [ 'today', 'tomorrow' ]

    await browser.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```